# Looping and Assigning results to Textboxes

Tags: c#

I have a linq query that pulls down some records. It could be 1 record, 2 records or 30 records. I have two textboxes I want the records to go into if there is only 1 record or only 2 records then it if its over that it puts it in a dropdownlist. This is what I have so far.

```
var getContacts = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference) r["accountid"]).Id
equals c["accountid"]
where r["accountid"].Equals(ddlCustomer.SelectedValue)
select new
{
    FirstName = !c.Contains("firstname") ? string.Empty : c["firstname"],
    LastName = !c.Contains("lastname") ? string.Empty : c["lastname"],
});

foreach (var contact in getContacts)
{
    if (getContacts.ToList().Count() == 1)
    {
        txtContact1Name.Text = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName;
    }
    else if (getContacts.ToList().Count() == 2)
    {
        txtContact2Name.Text = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName;
    }
    else if (getContacts.ToList().Count() > 2)
    {
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataSource = getContacts;
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataTextField = "LastName";
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataValueField = "LastName";
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But it puts the same record in textbox 1 and textbox two if there are two records. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: when you use count it counts the umber of objects in a list not number of values in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it puts the same record in textbox 1 and textbox two if there are two records. Am I doing something wrong?

Yes. Look at your code:

```
if (getContacts.ToList().Count() == 2)
```

You're calling that on each iteration - you're not using the count of how many contacts you've already used. I suspect you want:

```
// Let's only materialize the results *once* instead of once per iteration...
var contacts = getContacts().ToList();
switch (contacts.Count)
{
    case 0: // What do you want to do here?
        break;
    case 1:
        txtContact1Name.Text = FormatName(contacts[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        txtContact1Name.Text = FormatName(contacts[0]);
        txtContact2Name.Text = FormatName(contacts[1]);
        break;
    default:
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataSource = contacts;
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataTextField = "LastName";
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataValueField = "LastName";
        ddlMultipleContacts.DataBind();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getContacts = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
                           join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference) r["accountid"]).Id
                               equals c["accountid"]
                           where r["accountid"].Equals(ddlCustomer.SelectedValue)
                           select new
                                      {
                                          FirstName = !c.Contains("firstname") ? string.Empty : c["firstname"],
                                          LastName = !c.Contains("lastname") ? string.Empty : c["lastname"],
                                      }).ToList();


        if (getContacts.Count > 2)
        {
            ddlMultipleContacts.DataSource = getContacts;
            ddlMultipleContacts.DataTextField = "LastName";
            ddlMultipleContacts.DataValueField = "LastName";
            ddlMultipleContacts.DataBind();
        }
        else if (getContacts.Count == 1)
        {
            txtContact1Name.Text = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName;
        }
        else if (getContacts.Count == 2)
        {
            txtContact1Name.Text = contact[0].FirstName + " " + contact[0].LastName;
            txtContact2Name.Text = contact[1].FirstName + " " + contact[1].LastName;
        }
```